# Edit contents on product page catalog_product_view help

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product, catalog, magento-2.1.7

I am trying to add some text below this in a magento 2 store (see image):

[image]
When I inspect element I find the div responsible is:

```
<div class="title-wrapper"><div class="page-title-wrapper product">
```

I have then opened up `catalog_product_view.xml` and found the line of code which I think renders this:

```
<container name="page.main.title.wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="title-wrapper" before="-" >
```

My question is how do I edit the HTML of that container (if that makes sense) so I can add a `<p>` tag in underneath.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using any purchased theme or using extended luma ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the right template with Template Path Hints

Stores → Settings → Configuration → Advanced → Developer → Expand the Debug section

[image: Template Path Hints]

This will highlight all template paths on the frontend

Comment: Thank you - I did not realise what this did! Instead of hacking my solution into another component do you know how I would add a new one here?

Comment: Sorry, it depends on many details, so can't help with adding blocks here without knowing details. Please, look how it's described in the [documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-walkthrough.html)